# Facing errors with running shell scripts at startup and poweroff

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, shutdown, startup

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to run 3 scripts at startup. They are named as follows: `voe.sh` `startUp.sh` and `runDown.sh`

The script voe.sh is the main file which will in turn call the other 2 files, depending on if the system is booting up or shutting down respectively.

I copied all the 3 files to the directory `/etc/init.d`. I then used `sysv-rc-conf` utility, to add them to appropriate run levels as follows:

```
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sysv-rc-conf --list voe
voe          0:off  1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sysv-rc-conf --list startUp
startUp      0:off  1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sysv-rc-conf --list runDown
runDown      0:off  1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

I checked the all the rc*.d directories and all of them have correct symbolic links to `/etc/init.d` directory where all the 3 scripts have been kept. The permissions of these scripts also seem to be correct:

```
shankar@shannkardell:/etc/init.d$ ls -l voe startUp runDown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2781 Apr 20 14:58 runDown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2576 Apr 20 14:57 startUp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2242 Apr 20 14:57 voe
```

Even after all this, when I restart my machine, my boot.log says:

```
/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: /etc/rc2.d/S20voe: not found
```

Also, I tried to test the voe.sh from another directory (where I had also kept the other 2 in the same directory) by running it as follows:

```
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sudo bash voe.sh start
Starting GT.M for shankarNow using node v4.2.6 (npm v2.14.12)
-su: startUp.sh: command not found
*
```

I am not an expert with Ubuntu. So if I could get any guidance on this issue, it would be great.

Thanks